# How to sort my listview columns in alphabetical order by just clicking the column just like in ms excel

Tags: vb.net, sorting, listview, alphabetical

As I said in the title I just need help on how can i sort my listview ites by just clicking the column just like soring in ms excel btw my list view items are read from my mysql database. thanks mates here is the screenshot of my form

[image]

I have ready many questions about this but they are all in c# or java :3

Comment: Google found me [**this**](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_listview_sort_clicked_column.html)

Comment: A DataGridView will do this for you automatically (and is much more appropriate of the data comes from a DB).  Since the ListView is **not** a grid, you'll have to write code to sort by anything other than the Item/column 0.

Comment: Thank you very much @equisde and our bestfriend google ♥

Comment: I cant seem to connect my database with data grid but thanks btw its now solved! @Plutonix

Comment: You're welcome, but i must agree with @Plutonix